# How can I make Progress Bar work with ps2exe?

Tags: powershell, exe, ps2exe-gui

I have made a script that uses progress bars with the write-progress cmdlet that run fine in ISE or when executed with powershell as a .ps1 but when converted with ps2exe GUI and even with the parameter -noConsole the progress bars are not displayed at all. I havent found any info or solutions to this. I want my exe to be run in console and not with a GUI.

This is a snippet of the code:

```
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -File
$destinationFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Recurse -File

$matchedFiles = @()
$unmatchedFiles = @()

$totalFiles = $sourceFiles.Count
$filesVerified = 0

# Create a progress bar
$progress = @{
    Activity = "Verifying files"
    Status = "Elapsed time: 00:00:00"
    CurrentOperation = "$filesVerified out of $totalFiles files processed"
    PercentComplete = 0
}

# Start the timer
$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

# Show progress bar before processing the first file
Write-Progress @progress

foreach ($file in $sourceFiles) {
    $hash = Get-FileHash $file.FullName -Algorithm MD5
    $destinationFile = $destinationFiles | Where-Object { $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($destination), $source -eq $file.FullName }
    if ($destinationFile) {
        $hashDestination = Get-FileHash $destinationFile.FullName -Algorithm MD5
        if ($hash.Hash -eq $hashDestination.Hash) {
            Write-Host "$($file.Name) matches" -ForegroundColor Green
            $matchedFiles += [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name = $file.Name;
                SourceHash = $hash.Hash;
                DestinationHash = $hashDestination.Hash;
            }
        } else {
            Write-Host "$($file.Name) does not match" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
            $unmatchedFiles += [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name = $file.Name;
                Directory = $file.DirectoryName
                SourceHash = $hash.Hash;
                DestinationHash = $hashDestination.Hash;
            }
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "$($file.Name) does not exist in destination" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
        $unmatchedFiles += [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $file.Name;
            SourceHash = $hash.Hash;
            DestinationHash = "";
        }
    }

    # Update progress bar
    $filesVerified++
    $progress.Status = "Elapsed time: $($timer.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss"))"
    $progress.CurrentOperation = "$filesVerified out of $totalFiles files processed"
    $progress.PercentComplete = ($filesVerified / $totalFiles) * 100
    Write-Progress @progress
}
```

I tried different versions of ps2exe with no luck, also tried running the ps1 with powershell 7, not sure why but I did. The progress bar had a different format but worked.